# Tab completion when `patch` asks for filename

Tags: filenames, autocomplete, patch

When the patch command doesn't find the file to patch, it asks for a filename.

Is there any way to get this to use tab complete?

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
rlwrap -c patch -i patch.diff
```

rlwrap tries do add readline functionality to commands that lack it. There exists a couple of alternatives to rlwrap. If you're a zsh user, you may also have a look at [Using zsh's line editor to wrap around subprocesses](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5479/using-zshs-line-editor-to-wrap-around-subprocesses) and at `/usr/share/zsh/functions/Misc/nslookup` for an example of how to add the zsh line editor to a command.