# How to display control characters (^C, ^D, ^[, ...) differently in the shell

Tags: bash, colors, display, readline, special-characters

When you type control characters in the shell they get displayed using what is called "caret notation". Escape for example gets written as `^[` in caret notation.

I like to customize my bash shell to make it look cool. I have for example changed my `PS1` and `PS2` to become colorized. I now want control characters to get a unique appearance as well to make them more distinguishable from regular characters.

```
$ # Here I type CTRL-C to abort the command.
$ blahblah^C
          ^^ I want these two characters to be displayed differently
```

Is there a way to make my shell highlight control characters differently?

Is it possible to make it display them in a bold font or maybe make them appear in different colors from regular text?

I am using *bash* shell here but I did not tag the question with `bash` because maybe there is a solution that applies to many different shells.

**Note** that I do not know at what level highlighting of control characters takes place. I first thought it was in the shell itself. Now I have heard that it is *readline* that controls how control characters are in shells like *bash*. So the question is now tagged with `readline` and I am still looking for answers.

Comment: why do you think the shell is highlighting them? for `bash` it is `readline` handling that stuff, and for most others it is the tty driver.

Comment: I didn't know. That is why I wrote the note. It was just my guess because other applications like `vi` and `less` often highlight control characters differently from regular text. I will edit the question with this information. Thank you!

Comment: that makes sense. that kind of stuff is more difficult for a shell because its kind of a second priority. with editors their whole job is to provide a screen <> file interface, but the shell is a command interpreter for an interpreted language first and a line editor second *(or not at all)*.

Comment: Readline is used by other programs, but also it *is* part of bash: it is a library linked into it. And today's shells, especially bash, do pretty much anything you can think up.

Comment: Just use `zsh` which does that out of the box.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

When you press <kbd>Ctrl+X</kbd>, your terminal emulator writes the byte 0x18 to the master side of the pseudo-terminal pair.

What happens next depends on how the tty line discipline (a software module in the kernel that sits in between the master side (under control of the emulator) and the slave side (which applications running in the terminal interact with)) is configured.

A command to configure that *tty line discipline* is the `stty` command.

When running a dumb application like `cat` that is not aware of and doesn't care whether its stdin is a terminal or not, the terminal is in a default *canonical* mode where the tty line discipline implements a crude *line editor*.

Some interactive applications that need more than that crude *line editor* typically change those settings on start-up and restore them on leaving. Modern shells, *at their prompt* are examples of such applications. They implement their own more advanced line editor.

Typically, while you enter a command line, the shell puts the tty line discipline in that mode, and when you press enter to run the current command, the shell restores the normal tty mode (as was in effect before issuing the prompt).

If you run the `stty -a` command, you'll see the current settings in use for the *dumb applications*. You're likely to see the `icanon`, `echo` and `echoctl` settings being enabled.

What that means is that:

- `icanon`: that crude line editor is enabled.
- `echo`: characters you type (that the terminal emulator writes to the master side) are *echoed* back (made available for reading by the terminal emulator).
- `echoctl`: instead of being *echoed* asis, the control characters are *echoed* as `^X`.

So, let's say you type <kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>B</kbd> <kbd>Backspace-aka-Ctrl+H/?</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl+X</kbd> <kbd>Backspace</kbd> <kbd>Return</kbd>.

Your terminal emulator will send: `AB\bC\x18\b\r`. The line discipline will *echo* back: `AB\b \bC^X\b \b\b \b\r\n`, and an application that reads the input from the slave side (`/dev/pts/x`) will read `AC\n`.

All the application sees is `AC\n`, and only when your press <kbd>Enter</kbd> so it can't have any control on the output for `^X` there.

You'll notice that for *echo*, the first `^H` (`^?` with some terminals, see the `erase` setting) resulted in `\b \b` being sent back to the terminal. That's the sequence to move the cursor back, overwrite with space, move cursor back again, while the second `^H` resulted in `\b \b\b \b` to erase those two `^` and `X` characters.

The `^X` (0x18) itself was being translated to `^` and `X` for output. Like `B`, it didn't make it to the application, as we deleted it with Backspace.

`\r` (aka `^M`) was translated to `\r\n` (`^M^J`) for echo, and `\n` (`^J`) for the application.

So, what are our options for those *dumb* applications:

- disable `echo` (`stty -echo`). That effectively changes the way control characters are echoed, by... not echoing anything. Not really a solution.
- disable `echoctl`. That changes the way control characters (other than `^H`, `^M`... and all the other ones used by the line editor) are echoed. They are then *echoed* as-is. That is for instance, the ESC character is send as the `\e` (`^[`/`0x1b`) byte (which is recognised as the start of an escape sequence by the terminal), `^G` you send a `\a` (a BEL, making your terminal beep)... Not an option.
- disable the crude line editor (`stty -icanon`). Not really an option as the crude applications would become a lot less usable.
- edit the kernel code to change the behaviour of the tty line discipline so the *echo* of a control character sends `\e[7m^X\e[m` instead of just `^X` (here `\e[7m` usually enables reverse video in most terminals).

An option could be to use a wrapper like `rlwrap` that is a dirty hack to add a fancy line editor to dumb applications. That wrapper in effect tries to replace simple `read()`s from the terminal device to calls to readline line editor (which do change the mode of the tty line discipline).

Going even further, you could even try solutions like [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/46383) that hijacks all input from the terminal to go through zsh's line editor (which happens to highlight `^X`s in reverse video) relying on GNU screen's `:exec` feature.

Now for applications that do implement their own line editor, it's up to them to decide how the *echo* is done. `bash` uses readline for that which doesn't have any support for customizing how control characters are echoed.

For `zsh`, see:

```
info --index-search='highlighting, special characters' zsh
```

`zsh` does highlight non-printable characters by default. You can customize the highlighting with for instance:

```
zle_highlight=(special:fg=white,bg=red)
```

For white on red highlighting for those special characters.

The text representation of those characters is not customizable though.

In a UTF-8 locale, 0x18 will be rendered as `^X`, `\u378`, `\U7fffffff` (two unassigned unicode code points) as `<0378>`, `<7FFFFFFF>`, `\u200b` (a not-really printable unicode character) as `<200B>`.

`\x80` in a iso8859-1 locale would be rendered as `^�`... etc.

Answer (score 4):

I usally have this code in my .bashrc file:

```
function get_exit_status()
{
        local code=$?
        if [ $code -ne 0 ]
        then
                printf $'\001\033[31m\002'"($code)"$'\001\033[0m\002'" "
        fi
}
```

and then I call this function in my PS1

```
PS1='\u@\h \w $(get_exit_status)'
```

With this, if you press ^C you will see it in your prompt

```
I@mycomputer ~ ^C
I@mycomputer ~ (130)
```

All exit status codes that are not "0" will be prompted.

Comment: $? expands to exit status in the PS1  e.g   PS1='$?\u@\h \w '