# Displaying “^C” when I type ^C to abort a command

Tags: zsh

I’ve noticed that under Bash 4.4 (but not Bash 3.2), if I’m entering a command and then type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> to abort, the shell inserts the text `^C` at the cursor before displaying the new prompt line. Is there a way to configure zsh so that it does the same thing?

(This is sort of the opposite of [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/333766/88560), which is asking how to turn *off* this behavior, although that question is about Bash. [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/243651/88560) to another question shows how to get zle to highlight special characters when they appear in a command line, but I’m not inserting a literal 0x03 byte into the command line; I’m trying to get some text to appear when I type a control character.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works at least in simple cases:

```
precmd () {
  trap 'print -P "%B%F{red}^C%f%b"; zle send-break' INT
}
preexec () {
  trap - INT
}
```

I haven't explored how this works in “difficult” cases, such as a completion function that's taking too long.