# How to make C-[ generate a given control sequence?

Tags: x11, keyboard-shortcuts, wayland

The character with code `0x1B` (generated by `Ctrl+[`) is not meant to be used directly by applications, because it was designed to serve as the signal which starts a control sequence. I never input control sequences by hand (does anybody do?), thus I do not need any keybinding to produce the escape code itself. So, I would prefer to use these buttons for something else. You see, these two buttons (`Ctrl` and `[`) occupy a convenient place on the keyboard and are thus convenient to type, and it's a pity that this keybinding is just wasted.

How do I make `Ctrl+[` generate the control sequence of my choice? (both under X and under Wayland)

Comment: `Ctrl+[` here is an alternate way of inputting `Escape` and is supplied by the terminal driver, not XKB (the keyboard-config layer in both modern X11 and Wayland).  `stty` will let you query and set terminal settings, but i dunno how you'd change that one without breaking things like ... the terminal.  XKB would allow you to remap a `Ctrl` key to a modifier (eg `Alt`, `Hyper`, or `Super`), but then it wouldn't act like a `Ctrl` key anywhere, which might not be what you want.  see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code

Comment: (*you* may not be manually entering control sequences, but those characters are what allow ANSI colors in your shell prompts and curses libraries.)

Comment: @quixotic right, and for colors to work there need not be a keybinding on keyboard which generates the escape code (`0x1B`). I wonder how changing a keybinding may break the terminal

Comment: see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/243651 for a better explanation of the various layers of terminal handling.  (these are not keybindings in the same way that Ctrl+C/Ctrl+V doing Copy/Paste in your browser are keybindings.)

Comment: Translating from keychords to escape sequences is the job of the terminal emulator. Which terminal emulator are you using? It's also possible to remap Ctrl+[ to something like Ctrl+F13 with XKB, but even then some terminal emulators may not have an escape sequence for it. And there's a [terminal feature that allows terminal applications to distinguish](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/220/how-to-bind-c-i-as-different-from-tab/20290#20290) between Ctrl+[ and ESC but it only works in a few terminal emulators and not all applicatoins can cope with it.